# Array to string conversion. using laravel 8

Tags: laravel-8

i am trying to send email but unfortunately i am getting error please help me how can i resolved that ? thank u.

please check error.
https://flareapp.io/share/J7opZD25

**app\Http\Controllers\UserBookingController.php**

```
   public function memberBookingUserSummaryStore($random_code){

         $room = Room::where('random_code',$random_code)->first();
        $booking  = Booking::with('bookingDetails')->where('room_id',$room->id)
        ->orderBy('id','DESC')->first();

            $details = [
                'email'              =>    Auth::user()->email,
                'full_name'          =>    Auth::user()->full_name,
                'name'               =>    $room->name,
                'start_date'         =>    Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s',$booking->start_datetime)->format('d-M-Y'),
                'end_date'           =>    Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s',$booking->end_datetime)->format('d-M-Y'),
                'start_time'         =>    Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s',$booking->start_datetime)->format('H:i a'),
                'end_time'           =>    Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s',$booking->end_datetime)->format('H:i a')
           ];

            \Mail::to($details['email'])->send(new \App\Mail\UserBookingMail($details));
        }
        else{
            return redirect()->back()->withInput()->with('errorMsg', 'Your  Points is insufficient to make this booking.');
        }


       return redirect()->route('booking.success',$random_code);

    }
```

**app\Mail\UserBookingMail.php**

```
class UserBookingMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $details;
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($details)
    {
        $this->$details  = $details;

    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('web.emails.user_booking_mail')->with([
            'details'  => $this->details,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
public $details;
    
public function __construct($details)
{
    $this->$details = $details;
}
```

should be:

```
public $details;
    
public function __construct($details)
{
    $this->details = $details;
}
```